# Não estou conseguindo achar o maior valor em uma lista com valores aleatórios

Tags: python, lista, números-aleatórios

Eu preciso achar o maior valor em uma lista de 50 números aleatórios. Para gerar esse números, eu usei as funções `sample` e `randint`. Então, para gerar a lista eu uso:

```
lista = [sample(range(0, 200), 50)]
```

E para achar o maior eu uso:

```
mai = 0
for v in lista:
    if v == 0:
        mai = v
    else:
        if v > mai:
            mai = v
print(f'O maior valor da lista é {mai}')
```

Mas, sempre que eu uso algumas dessas funções ele retorna esse erro: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'` e se eu gerar uma lista manualmente, esse método de achar o maior funciona perfeitamente, o que eu posso fazer pra contornar esse problema? Eu já tentei por a lista gerada dentro de outra lista e mesmo assim não funciona, se alguém puder ajudar eu ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você recebe esse erro porque está colocando colchetes no seu sample, mas a função sample já retorna uma lista.

**random.sample(population, k)**
    *Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.*

Portanto o resultado que você tem é mais ou menos assim:

```
   [[60, 93, 22, 57, 164, 79, 24, 92, 104, 114, 120, 59, 191, 137, 186, 31, 51, 35, 165, 18, 74, 95, 99, 116, 63, 141, 173, 105, 185, 27, 52, 80, 112, 159, 188, 67, 36, 108, 34, 1, 75, 40, 84, 138, 190, 119, 194, 6, 4, 82]]
```

Quando chega na linha `if v > mai:` você está comparando uma lista com um int.

Para resolver o problema é só tirar os colchetes do seu sample:

```
lista = sample(range(0, 200), 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra maneira mais pythonica de responder é utilizando a função `max` que é fornecida pelo python.

```
from random import sample
lista = sample(range(0, 200), 50)
print('O maior elemento é: {}'.format(max(lista)))
```